# Fiddler - Daily stop start

Tags: scheduled-tasks, fiddler

What is the best way to stop/start Fiddler as a daily task?
I am usin Fiddler to monitor/logs https trafficon machine which runs fully automated and runs software which is not controlled by me, but uses https.
My machine stopped yesterday because Fiddler went out of memory after running over 3 days and now I want to have a clean way to start/stop it.
I guess I could just specify a process duration in the task manager, but I would prefer something cleaner, especially to avoid issues when things are started manually.

Comment: You do know that you can stop and restart capturing traffic by clicking the status bar on the bottom left? ;-)

Comment: it is a fully automated machine - I will simply go for the schedulded tasks - was not aware of TaskKill before...

Comment: Fiddler probably isn't the right tool for your needs (FiddlerCap or FiddlerCore are probably better bets). 

If you want to use Fiddler, you should configure it to log to a database instead of keeping all of your web traffic in RAM indefinitely.

Comment: I do not necessarily need a database - I am happy with text files as they are easier to search through anyway. Can FiddlerCap run also via the command line?

Comment: You could store text files if you prefer... the point is only to get the sessions out of memory.

FiddlerCore is what you should be using if you want to only have a command-line environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Scheduled Tasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler), they have been part of windows since forever. You should be able to stop fiddler with it too (by calling [`TaskKill`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)).

Comment: I have added Fiddler as a scheduled task, to run on Start Up(without user need for log in). That machine is used for running automated tests and they all fail, as the requests are not going through Fiddler.
When I log in I can see in Task Manager that that fiddler is running as background process though.